# JRuby Cassandra Problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, cassandra

I am using Jruby to connect Cassandra and ruby. I am developing a code which had to interact with cassandra from Rails. I have configured and installed jruby. I also did the "import" for all the dependencies for both cassandra and jruby. I am getting issues when running the file. I am getting error like this.

==================================================================================

```
org/apache/thrift/transport/TIOStreamTransport.java:132:in `read': org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: null (NativeException)
    from org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport.java:84:in `readAll'
    from org/apache/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.java:378:in `readAll'
    from org/apache/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.java:297:in `readI32'
    from org/apache/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.java:204:in `readMessageBegin'
    from org/apache/cassandra/thrift/Cassandra.java:1062:in `recv_describe_cluster_name'
    from org/apache/cassandra/thrift/Cassandra.java:1048:in `describe_cluster_name'
    from sun/reflect/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2:in `invoke0'
    from sun/reflect/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39:in `invoke'
     ... 13 levels...
    from org/jruby/Main.java:203:in `run'
    from org/jruby/Main.java:100:in `run'
    from org/jruby/Main.java:84:in `main'
```

==============================================================================

Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your code, it is hard to debug from just the stack trace.

It looks like you are using raw thrift, there is a [jruby wrapper](https://github.com/jashmenn/hector.rb) for the java cassandra client library [hector](https://github.com/rantav/hector) that will be easier to use.